# SQL Server value help

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Hey all, is there any SQL Server 2005 guru that can tell me a type of trick to get the values of what is being queried?

Ex:

```
 UPDATE l SET Inactive = 1 
 FROM tbl1 e JOIN tbl2 l ON l.CID = e.CID
     JOIN tbl3 p ON p.PID = e.PID
     JOIN tbl4 c ON c.PID = e.PID
     LEFT JOIN tbl5 g ON g.EID = e.ID 
         AND g.PID = e.PID
 WHERE e.PID = '315' 
 AND Inactive = 0 
 AND (e.Active = 0 OR g.ID IS NULL)
```

How can I get the values of, say, e.CID after this executes? I've already tried

```
 Print e.CID
```

But of course that does not work. Any other way to do that?

Thanks!

David

Comment: Are you trying to see which rows are being used to update your table? Is there a reason that you can't just run the code adjusted to use SELECT instead of UPDATE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the OUTPUT clause:

```
UPDATE l 
SET Inactive = 1 
OUTPUT e.CID
FROM tbl1 e 
  JOIN tbl2 l ON l.CID = e.CID
  JOIN tbl3 p ON p.PID = e.PID
  JOIN tbl4 c ON c.PID = e.PID
  LEFT JOIN tbl5 g ON g.EID = e.ID AND g.PID = e.PID
WHERE e.PID = '315' 
AND Inactive = 0 
AND (e.Active = 0 OR g.ID IS NULL)
```

That should show the `e.CID` column for each row being updated as a result set from your UPDATE query.